# Multiple posters on page

Tags: facebook, accounts

I have a question, It might be found somewhere but I couldnt find a thread for it so if there is one, please post the link.

I admin a page that is a group of several other business areas. I want to post on one page with different icons and names, can that be done? Like different admins but administered by one person/account?

Possible?

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding exactly what you are trying to achieve..  You want to post to a page as a user? as an administrator?  Please could you provide some more information and describe the scenario.

Comment: Sorry, My english is a bit rough.

Comment: I want to post as an administrator, or different administrators. Lets say I have 6 different administrator profiles (names, and logo) that can post the same wall?

Comment: Do you want to post as the **page**?

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to want to do is use a "Page `access_token`". To get this you will have to create an application and grant it the `manage_pages` permission.

You should see in the [Authentication Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140123045312/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) a section called "Page Login".

You can grant your application the `manage_pages` permission by going to this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token
```

Don't forget to substitute `YOUR_APP_ID` and `YOUR_URL` with the correct values for you application and URL.  (the URL can be any URL - it is where Facebook will send you after you close the Dialog).  You will see a dialog that looks something like this :

[image]
<sub>(source: [facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/manage_pages.png))</sub>

Once you have the correct permission, you'll want to make a call to this URL :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE
```

You will get a response similar to :

[image]
<sub>(source: [facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/page_tokens.png))</sub>

As you can see from the image, you will receive a list of all the pages that the user administers along with an `access_token` for each page.
You use this `access_token` to make posts on behalf of the page.  Since you have not stated what programming language you are using I will give an example in [php](/questions/tagged/php).
In [php](/questions/tagged/php), posting to the page would look something like this :

```
$facebook->setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN_YOU_RETRIEVED_EARLIER);

$attachment = array('message' => 'this is my message',
                'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
                'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
                'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
                'description' => 'this is a description',
                'picture' => 'http://example.com/pic.gif',
                'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
                                  'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
                );


$result = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/','post',$attachment);
```

Hope this helps!
Happy coding!